# Exception thrown when listing Android AVDs on Linux

Tags: android, linux, command-line

Any clue on why I get the exception below on Linux?

```
[rusty@fs0 avd]$ android list avd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1459)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1435)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:343)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:353)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.getAvdManager(Main.java:294)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.displayAvdList(Main.java:1184)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:320)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```